# How to check whether two element's text content matches?

Tags: javascript

I am creating Hangman game. I want when the button is clicked to be checked whether some of the hidden letters matches the clicked button

```
for(let i = 0; i < letters.length; i++){
        let letter = letters[i]
        let hiddenLetters = document.querySelectorAll('.hidden')
        hiddenLetters = Array.from(hiddenLetters)
        letter.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
            let check = hiddenLetters.some((hiddenLetter)=>{hiddenLetter.textContent == letter.textContent})
            if(check){
                console.log('works')
            } else{
                console.log('doesnt')
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have your `hiddenLetters` in a string. I would suggest you store individual letters in an array that way its easier to compare/check if the letters exist.

Something like this should get you going.

```js
const checkIfLettersExist = (hiddenLetters, letters) => {
   return hiddenLetters.some(hdnLetter => letters.includes(hdnLetter));
}

const hiddenText = "name";
const hiddenLetters = hiddenText.split('');
let letters = ['a','b'];

const check = checkIfLettersExist(hiddenLetters, letters);
(check ? console.log("works") : console.log("doesn't"));
```